# How would you define a "solved" or "complete" theory?

Tags: soft-question

I met this phrase a couple of times. I remember the the teacher in my complex analysis course using it in regard to the theory of analytic functions in $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. I also think I heard it in regard to finitly generated abelian groups, because of the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups.

However, I don't have any formal definition.

Comment: I would agree with this description for finitely generated abelian groups, because it’s hard to imagine anyone coming up with anything new and interesting about them, because of the fundamental theorem. But I disagree with calling the theory of analytic functions complete or solved. It’s true that the theory is well worked over, but people do come up with new wrinkles from time to time. E.g., https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2021/05/04/is-there-a-non-analytic-function-with-all-differences-analytic/, or https://www.math.ttu.edu/~rbarnard/Papers/Open_Problems_Conjectures_Complex_Analysis.pdf

Comment: Thank you, I will check this out.